# AttributeError while setting up a flask app on a cPanel

Tags: python, flask, cpanel

I'm currently trying to run my flask project on my cPanel (o2switch), but I get an error.
Here's my `test.py` file:

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

and my `passenger_wsgi.py` file:

```py
from test import app
```

My python project is set like this:[image: Python project setup]

I get this error when I try to access it:

```py
AttributeError: module 'passenger_wsgi' has no attribute 'application'
```

It might be something very easy, but I couldn't find anything else on google and the only thing I found is giving me this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `passenger_wsgi.py` to add this line:

```
from test import app
application = app
```

It looks like you should be able to set the name of the application entry point, but for whatever reason it is still looking for `application` instead of `app`